# (this question is from linear algebra done right 2.C question 9?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose v1,v2....... vm is linearly independent in V and w belong V. Prove that
dim span(v1 +w ,v2+w,v3+w,......,vm+w) \ge m-1.(this question is from linear algebra done right 2.C question 9

my attempts: here w is not equal to zero.i takie v2+w -(v1 + w) , v3+w-(v1+w),,,,,,,vn+w-(v1+w)
i got v2-v1,v3-v1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,vn-v1,but i don't know how to show it is linearly independent.

Comment: have anyone showed you [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) before?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Start by showing that 
$$
\dim \operatorname{span}(v_1 + w,v_2 + w,\dots,v_m + w,w) \geq m
$$
If we take a list and remove one vector, then the dimension of the span of the list goes down by at most $1$.  Why?